# Syntax of bash alias definition

Tags: bash, alias

I'm using Cygwin, and have installed all the developer packages as well as most if not all of the other packages. When I provide an alias for gcc, I get the error

```
-bash: alias: gcc: not found
```

What could I be doing wrong?

I am typing the following command into the terminal:

```
alias gcc "gcc -ansi -Wall -g -O0 -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow -pedantic-errors -fstack-protector-all"
```

FYI, this alias works on other systems.

Comment: What do you mean by "provide an alias for"? What command are you typing, exactly?

Comment: @steeldriver I am typing the following command into the terminal: alias gcc "gcc -ansi -Wall -g -O0 -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow -pedantic-errors -fstack-protector-all"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your alias assignment syntax is wrong for bash/zsh/fish (your syntax is tcsh), you need a `=` between alias name and alias expansion:

```
alias gcc="gcc -ansi -Wall -g -O0 -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow -pedantic-errors -fstack-protector-all"
```

If you omit the `=`, bash interprets `gcc` and `"gcc -ansi ..." as two alias names and tries to list their definitions. Since those aliases aren't defined, you get the warning:

```
bash: alias: gcc: not found
bash: alias: gcc -ansi -Wall -g -O0 -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow -pedantic-errors -fstack-protector-all: not found
```

Comment: I spent the whole afternoon trying to solve what you just answered in a second! You don't know how much this means to me. Thanks!