# creating alias in bashrc in wsl

Tags: alias, bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to create alias for for cd command to AppData and %programdata% folders but I got path not found while if  I write manual it works, here is what I'm doing:

In .bashrc I do

```
alias client= 'cd /mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/'
alias driver= 'cd /mnt/c/ProgramData/
```

the error is

```
-bash: alias: cd /mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/: not found
-bash: alias: cd /mnt/c/ProgramData/: not found
```

however in the terminal `cd mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/`, will navigate me to the folders

Comment: Related: [Syntax of bash alias definition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262143/syntax-of-bash-alias-definition)

Comment: There should be no space between the `=` and the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple syntax error: no space before or after `=`.

Change this:

```
alias client= 'cd /mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/'
alias driver= 'cd /mnt/c/ProgramData/'
```

To this:

```
alias client='cd /mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/'
alias driver='cd /mnt/c/ProgramData/'
```